# git stash --patch not rolling back stashed changes from worktree when any hunk is split

Tags: git

When `git stash --patch` is used to selectively stash changes, it works as documented when none of the hunk is split into smaller changes with the interactive command for doing so.

If any change is split during the interactive stash, then although git creates a correct stash of the designated changes, it does not roll back any of the stashed changes from the working tree.

As a workaround, I have been doing something like this:

```
$ git commit                 # temporary work-in-progress commit
$ git diff stash@{0} > diffs # obtain stashed changes as a diff
$ git reset                  # undo temp. commit
$ git apply < diffs          # remove stashed changes
```

Is there a way to get the desired behavior out of `git stash` in one step?

(I'm on 1.7.9.5)