# Undo "git stash --patch"

Tags: git

I executed "git stash -p" (equivalent to "git stash --patch") which successfully stashed part of the changes that I had made to the code.  When I tried to run "git stash pop" it gave me the following message:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
>
> ```
> [list of files]
> ```
>
> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
>
> Aborting

How can I get all of my changes back?  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23642177/724157) appears to have a method (haven't tried it yet), but I was hoping for something cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I just into the same problem. Here is what I did:

```
$ git stash --patch
# now you have a 'partial' stash
#
# commit all changes in your working tree
$ git add .
$ git commit -m TEMP
# pop the stash
$ git stash pop
# now your stashed changes have been applied successfully
#
# reset your working tree to the original state
$ git reset --soft HEAD^^
# optionally reset your index
$ git reset .
```

This resets your working tree to the state before the `git stash`. The changes to your index will we lost.